# Issue on calling drupal web service from non drupal site

Tags: web-services, drupal, service

I am using Drupal 6 with services 6.x-2.0x and using beecolony module when i making a call to log in to my drupal site through drupal web service from a non-drupal site(mobile app) it asks me to pass on session id .. we don't get session id until i logged in to my drupal site...

How to use this web services !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make use of the session id authentication option you need to make a call, before anything else, to `system.connect`.

`system.connect` is a special service which does not require a session id. What it does is that it creates a new entry in the session table and returns a session id to you which you'll need to save and use for all the other web service calls.